# java 8 stream creating collection of type B from collection of type A

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to create a collection of type A from type B, using streams.

Suppose I have two classes

```
Class Employee{
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   int age;
   String id;
   String email;
   double salary;
}

Class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;
}
```

To create collection of Person from collection of Employee, I've writing following code

```
public static List<Person> createPersonsFromEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        employees.stream().filter(Object :: nonNull)
                  .forEach(e -> {
                       persons.add(new Person(e.getFirstName(),
                                           e.getLastName(), 
                                           e.getEmail());
                   };)


        return persons;
}
```

Currently, this piece of code works. But I'm wondering and would like to know if there is a better way to create a collection of `Person` from `Employee` without using `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping an `Employee` to a `Person` you can use [Collectors.mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)/[Stream.map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) that others has already provided so I will skipped it.

Notes that mapping way is faster than  map then collect way, because `collect(mapping(...))` is O(N) but `map(...).collect(...)` is O(2N), but `map(...).collect(...)` more readable than `collect(mapping(...))`,  and `mapping` refer to a public `transform(Employee)` method reference instead of `Function<Employee,Person>` which will be reused as a method to transform an `Employee` to a `Person`. and then two `transform` method have the same semantics, they both are [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) methods.

```
public List<Person> transform(List<Employee> employees) throws Throwable {
    return employees.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.mapping(this::transform, Collectors.toList()));
}

public Person transform(Employee it) {
    return new Person(it.firstName, it.lastName, it.email);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for lots of explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a little cleaner way of doing it.  Using .forEach() in a stream is a sign that there are probably better ways to use Stream.  Streams are meant to be be functional and they try to stay away from mutability.

```
public static List<Person> createPersonsFromEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
    Function<Employee, Person> employeeToPerson = e -> new Person(e.getFirstName, e.getLaseName(), e.getEmail());

    return employees.stream()
                    .filter(Object :: nonNull)
                    .map(employeeToPerson)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. The only thing I would change is to create a Builder for the Person class to handle the fields in the constructor in a smarter way.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your thoughts and your inputs, on how to make it better.

Answer (score 3):

Create Adapter class:

```
class EmployeeToPersonAdapter {

    private EmployeeToPersonAdapter() {
    }

    public static Person toPerson(Employee employee) {
        if (employee == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Person(employee.getFirstName(),
                employee.getLastName(),
                employee.getEmail());
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
public static List<Person> createPersonsFromEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(EmployeeToPersonAdapter::toPerson)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for sparing your time and also sharing a solution.